# Why does it generate same hash code for both string objects?

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

I am new to Java programming, I want to create are multiple numbers of strings, for that I written the code below. Why does it generate same hash code for both string objects?

```
   class SingletonClass {
            public static String mystring="this"; 
        }
        public class SingletonObjectDemo {
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                String str = SingletonClass.mystring;
                String str2 = SingletonClass.mystring;
                System.out.println("String str  "+str.hashCode());
                System.out.println("String str1  "+str2.hashCode());
                    }
        }
```

Comment: For completeness, I'll add to the answers below that you'd still get the same hash code for two different String objects with the same characters in them. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29).

Comment: Your misconception is that the code `String str` defines an _object_. Indeed, this code declares only a _reference_ to some existing object. The objects are usually created with `new`, but for strings there are _literals_ (like `"this"`) which define string objects as well. The code `String str = SingletonClass.mystring` just assigns one reference to another one, no object cloning is done.

Comment: Why is none of the answers to this question accepted yet? Just click on the outlied check mark on the left of your favourite answer...

Answer (score 2):

It's generating the same hash code for both string objects...because they're the same object.

Comment: but i am assigning to 2 different objects of string as str,str2

Comment: No.  `str` and `str2` are two different references to the same `String` object.  In any event, two strings with the same contents always have the same hash code, so as long as `str` and `str2` are both `"this"`, they'll have the same hash code.

Comment: @user1335578 no, you aren't.  You're assigning the same static String to two method local references.

Comment: Even if they had different references, hashCode() would have been the same.

Comment: (To clarify @Chip's statement, that's because `str` and `str2` have the same contents -- they're both `"this"`.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes - I just wanted to distinguish the fact that the reason the hashCode() is same is that the contents are same ( as you said ). So even if they were references to different objects, as long as they are .equals("this") they would have the same hashcode().

Answer (score 2):

They reference the same object in memory, there is in essence no difference..

Comment: Even if they had different references, hashCode() would have been the same.

Comment: @Chip: ... provided their _contents_ is the same, i.e. they are composed of the same characters in the same order.

Comment: @Vlad yes.. as long as str1.equals(str2)

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing objects with references to them. When you write `String str = "a", str2 = "a";` you are not creating two strings, but declaring two variables which contain the exact same reference, to the string constant "a".

Even if they were two objects, as in `String str = new String("a"), str2 = new String("a")` the `hashCode`s would still be the same because for equal objects their hashcodes must match — that's the essential property of a hashcode.

But, if you wrote `Object o = new Object(), o2 = new Object()`, now the hashcodes would be different because no two instances of `Object` are equal (according to the definition of equality for the `Object` class).

Answer (score 0):

You say you "want to create to multiple number of strings" but you are using something called SingletonObjectDemo. The point of a singleton is that there will only be one object, no matter how many times you "create it", so you can't create multiple objects. As Louis explains, that's why the hash code returns the same.

Comment: There are no singletons involved in the example. There's only a class with a static member, which is a string constant. So, theoretically, you could call the string "test" itself to be a singleton, but that's stretching the terms quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the property of a good hashcode.

If A and B are objects such that A.equals(B), then the following property should hold.

A.hashCode().equals(B.hashCode())

You can read about hashCode and equals() [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html)

Comment: No, this is the property of any hashcode that complies with the specification. It *must* return equal hashcodes for equal objects. The canonical reference is not some third party site however august, but the [Javadoc for Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).