# same reference  for multiple objects..?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hash code for string objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615151/hash-code-for-string-objects)

Hi I am new to java programming,i want to create to multiple number of obj of Myclass, for that written the code Below.why does it generating same objects

```
class Myclass {

        private static Myclass single;
        private Myclass() {

        }
        public static synchronized Myclass obj() {
            if (single == null) {
                single = new Myclass();
            }
            return single;
        }
    }
    public class Demo {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Myclass obj = Myclass.obj();
            System.out.println("one  "+obj);
            Myclass obj1 = Myclass.obj();
            System.out.println("two  "+obj1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615151/hash-code-for-string-objects/

Comment: @epoch *bangs head repeatedly on desk*

Comment: Stop flooding SO and read up on basic Java facts!

Comment: Could someone please recommend for the OP a nice beginner's Java reference?

Answer (score 1):

It is single instance in fact , both are same object

Comment: but we are creating multiple objects of Myclass as Obj,obj1

Comment: google "singleton design pattern"

Comment: @user1335578 In my answer to your previous question I already explained just this aspect to you. You post a new question instead of reading answers to your first question??

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly designing MyClass.obj() to return a singleton, so you shouldn't be suprised that is returns the same instance - so both references point to the same object and have the same hashcode.